# $P\left( X_n = 0 \right)$ when $X_n$ is a random walk on the cyclic group $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: probability

Define the time set $T=\{0\}\cup\mathbb N$.
Let $X=\left( X_t \right)_{t \in T}$ be a random walk on the cyclic group $\mathbb Z _ 2 = \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$, where $X_0$ is uniformly drawn from $\mathbb Z_2$. That is
$$
P\left(X_{t} - X_{t-1} = 0 \right)
=\frac12
=P\left(X_{t} - X_{t-1} = 1 \right)
, \text{ for } t = T \setminus \{0\}. 
$$
Find $P\left( X_n = 0 \right)$ for a large $n$ in $T$.

I define
\begin{align}
s & \text{ number of moves where the walk stay at } 0; \\
r & \text{ number of roundtrip : a roundtrip is a move from 0 to 1, then back to 0 }; \\
e & \text{ number of moves where the walk stay at 1 between its roundtrips}.
\end{align}
The probability should be
$$
P\left(X_n=0 \right)=
\sum\left[ {\frac12}^s {\frac12}^r {\frac12}^e {\frac12}^r : s+2r+e=n, e \ne 0 \text{ iff } r \ne 0 \right].
$$
I don't see how to count the number of element in the sum, so that I can infer an expression for $P\left(X_n=0 \right)$.

Comment: I think you can compute $P(X_t=0)$ easily for $t=1$, and then for $t=2$. From this you should be able to extrapolate and prove the "formula" by induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that for $n \geq 1$, $$\mathrm{Pr}[X_n=0]=\begin{cases} 0.5 & \text{if } X_{n-1}=0 \\ 0.5 & \text{if } X_{n-1}=1 \end{cases}$$ and $$\mathrm{Pr}[X_n=1]=\begin{cases} 0.5 & \text{if } X_{n-1}=0 \\ 0.5 & \text{if } X_{n-1}=1. \end{cases}$$  Hence, $\mathrm{Pr}[X_n=0]=0.5$ and $\mathrm{Pr}[X_n=1]=0.5$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Completely agree, but I'd suggest explicitly showing the conditional probabilities, as in $Pr(X_n=0) = Pr(X_n=0\mid X_{n-1}=0)Pr(X_{n-1}=0) + Pr(X_n=0\mid X_{n-1}=1)Pr(X_{n-1}=1) = \frac{1}{2}\left(Pr(X_{n-1}=0)+Pr(X_{n-1}=1)\right) = \frac{1}{2}$