# Show that, for a random walk $X$ on $\mathbb Z_2$, $X_\infty$ is independent of the past $\left\{ X_t \right\}_{0\le t<\infty}$

Tags: probability-theory, nonstandard-analysis

Define the *-finite time set $T=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, with $n \in {^*\mathbb N} \setminus \mathbb N$.
Let $X=\left( X_t \right)_{t \in T}$ be a random walk on the cyclic group $\mathbb Z _ 2 = \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$, where $X_0$ is uniformly drawn from $\mathbb Z_2$. That is
$$
P\left(X_{t} - X_{t-1} = 0 \right)
=\frac12
=P\left(X_{t} - X_{t-1} = 1 \right)
, \text{ for } t = T \setminus \{0\}, 
$$
with $P$ the *-finite measure.
Show $X_n$ is independent of the finite time part of the process, that is
$$
\mathbf{P}\left(\left. X_n =  x \right| X_t, t \in {^\circ T}\right) =
\mathbf{P}\left( X_n =  x \right),
$$ 
where ${^\circ(\cdot)}=\text{st}(\cdot)$ is the standard part map,
and $\mathbf{P}$ is the Loeb measure.

Define $A = \left\{ X_t, t \in {^\circ T} \right\}$. My approach would be to repetitively conditioned on the penultimate time
\begin{align}
P\left(X_n=0 \mid A \right)
&= E\left( P\left(X_n=0 \mid X_{n-1}, A \right) \right) \\
&= \frac12 P\left(X_{n-1} =0\mid A \right) 
+ \frac12 P\left(X_{n-1} =1\mid A \right) \\
&= \frac12\left( \frac12 P\left(X_{n-2} =0\mid A \right)  
+ \frac12 P\left(X_{n-2} =1\mid A \right) \right)
+ \frac12\left( \frac12 P\left(X_{n-2} =0\mid A \right)  
+ \frac12 P\left(X_{n-2} =1\mid A \right) \right) \\
&= \ldots
\end{align} 
So, I end up with
$$
P\left( X_n=0 \mid A \right) = \frac12,
$$
and $X_n$ is [independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/480182/14108) of $A$.
I don't see how to 'jump' from infinite numbers of the form $n-t, t \in {^\circ T}$, to the finite numbers $t, t\in{^\circ T}$.
I guess I should use saturation or something like this.

Comment: (group-theory)? Really?

Comment: @Did I tagged too much. Thanks For letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the *-things and "standard part map" refer to but anyway, you might want to note (and prove) the following:

> Every random walk on $\mathbb Z_2$ with uniform initial distribution and uniform transition probabilities coincides with an i.i.d. sequence with uniform distribution on $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: By 'coincides', you mean in distribution: if $X$ is a random walk on $\mathbb Z_2$, as above, and $\left(Y_t\right)$ is an i.i.d sequence with uniform distribution on $\mathbb Z_2$. Then $X_t \buildrel{d}\over = Y_t, \forall t$. I don't see a proof for a stronger mode of convergence.

Comment: No *convergence* here, but the fact that (with your notations) the families $(X_t)_t$ and $(Y_t)_t$ are identically distributed.